# For loop conditional if step value in column equals 1

Tags: pandas

I have dataset. For a certain condition there is a column has True or False values. If there is a sequence of rows has the same value, then let the counter of these rows be the same.But I need also consider the step in row, if its greater than 1 then start new flag value 
To make it clear, below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, ExcelWriter
import numpy as np 
import datetime as dt 
file=pd.ExcelFile("6324_data.xlsx")
Dataframe=file.parse('sheet1')
c1 = Dataframe['change']
row_iterator = Dataframe.iterrows()
c1 = Dataframe['change']
res = []
var = 1
cur=c1[0]
d1=Dataframe['index_col']
flag = 0
Av=d1[0]
res.append(None)
row_iterator = Dataframe.iterrows()
idx, last = row_iterator.__next__()
for index, row in row_iterator:
    for val in c1[1:]:
        if val == cur and flag == 0:
            res.append(var)
        elif val == cur and flag == 1:
            var+=1
            flag = 0
            res.append(var)
        elif val != cur and flag == 0:
            flag = 1
            res.append(var)
        elif val != cur and flag == 1:
            res.append(var)
        else:
            pass
```

for example the current code brings this output

```
x2=[
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13]
```

While the expected output is

```
x2=[
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
13,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14,
14, 
15,
15,
15,
15,
15,
15,
15,
15,
15]
```

as far as the change in row index is as follows

```
row_index = [        
19327,
19328,
19329,
19330,
19331,
19332,
19333,
19334,
19335,
19336,
19337,
19338,
19339,
19340,
19341,
19342,
19343,
19344,
19345,
19346,
19347,
19348,
19349,
19350,
19351,
19352,
19377,
19378,
19379,
19380,
19381,
19382,
19383,
19384,
19385,
19386,
19387,
19388,
19389,
19390,
19391,
19402,
19403,
19404,
19405,
19406,
19407,
19408,
19409,
19410
]
```

the step is greater than 1 after row index equals to  19352 and 19391.

How could I make my for loop depends only if step in row index or (Av) equals 1.

Comment: Can you provide a visual example of your data?

Comment: And the corresponding output you want?

Comment: @ggrelet check it again